# prepositions (punch in/on/to)

Tags: prepositions

I'd like to know if all these sentences are correct, and if there is a difference between them in meaning:

I punched him in the face.
I punched him on the face.
I punched him to the face.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you take a closer look, you can see that the question is "if the three sentences are different in meaning"...

Comment: @tchrist: Per Colin's answer, I think there's a degree of distinction between ***in*** and ***on*** (and in principle ***to***, which potentially would be an even looser contact, since it's just *towards, in the direction/general area of*). Arguably that's just common sense, but so are a lot of questions about *Why do we use that particular preposition?*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question. The usual expression is *punched him in the face*, and *punched him to the face* is not idiomatic at all.

*On the face* is possible, but unlikely, with *punched*, because *on* suggests a superficial contact. *I tapped him on the face* is possible (though perhaps an unlikely action), *I slapped him on the face* and *I slapped him in the face* are both possible, with *in* suggesting to me a bit more aggression than *on*.

Comment: Quite. In such contexts, ***in*** is more "invasive" - so all things being equal, if you *smacked him **in** the mouth* you probably caused more damage than if you *smacked him **on** the mouth*.